# C++ Pass method input arg an object reference instantiated right inline

Tags: c++

I have the following code. As you see in the code I can create an instance of MyClass in a stack and pass it to a method as input arg as reference object. I can in one line also pass to that method an instance created in a heap. What I was trying to find if there is a way to pass an instance of the class in line created in a stack. Is there a way to achieve it?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass
{
    int m_i;
    
    public:
        MyClass(int i) { m_i = i; }
        int GetIVal() { return m_i; }
};

void Print(MyClass & refObj)
{
    std::cout << refObj.GetIVal();
}

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    
    MyClass myObj(3);
    Print(myObj); //works
    Print(*(new MyClass(5))); //works
    Print(MyClass(7)); //doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last case does not work because *this is always a logic error*, and C++ catches this dangerous code (for once). If you want to pass a temporary, you need to either pass by value or by const reference.

Comment: ... So, with the code as given, `void Print(const MyClass & refObj)` would work.

Comment: No it wouldn't, because the `MyClass::GetIVal` method is then required to be const. However, that is also an error. It _should_ be const.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error helpful in identifying the problem, if you know how to interpret it:

> error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'MyClass&' to an rvalue of type 'MyClass'

Here, you're being informed that `MyClass(7)` is a rvalue, which you can roughly think of as a temporary / intermediate result. The language prohibits you from binding an rvalue to a reference type unless that reference is constant (`const MyClass&`) or is an *rvalue reference* (`MyClass&&`).

In this case, it's not appropriate to use an rvalue reference. That is typically used when transferring ownership of an object.

The correct approach for your case is to make your code *const-correct*. That is, whenever you're passing data that will only be read from (not written to), make it const. The same applies to accessors: If an accessor method does not make changes to the underlying object, it should be const. That way, it can be called on const objects.

```
class MyClass
{
    int m_i;
    
public:
    MyClass(int i) { m_i = i; }
    int GetIVal() const { return m_i; }
};

void Print(const MyClass & refObj)
{
    std::cout << refObj.GetIVal();
}
```